# How to add multiple conditions when joining spark data frames

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

The code I tried.
It's not working.

`df_join = df1.join(df2, df1.name == df2.name & df1.no == df2.no).drop("id")`

When I search for other methods, I only find the spark.sql method

Comment: You must isolate your conditions: `df1.join(df2, (df1.name == df2.name) & (df1.no == df2.no))`

Comment: Also you could run: `df1.join(df2, ['name', 'no'])`

Comment: @ushi Nier Please upvote if the answer solved your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like below

```
df_join = df1.join(df2, (df1.name == df2.name) & (df1.no == df2.no), how='inner')
```

This should solve your problem